# Clear the radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() from Radio Group

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I have a radiogroup which loads questions depending on the answer from the previous set of questions. It is the same radiogroup, only the questions change.

Here is code part where I load the questions;

```
if (key.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("CS")){
    actionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    radioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    radioGroup.removeAllViews();
    btnForward.setEnabled(true);

    Set optTextset=thisScreenOpts.lhmOptionText.entrySet();
    Set optAnswerSet=thisScreenOpts.lhmNextStep.entrySet();
    Iterator i=optTextset.iterator();
    Iterator i2=optAnswerSet.iterator();
    if (thisScreenOpts.title!=null){
        myText.setText(thisScreenOpts.title);
    }else{
        myText.setText("");
    }
    while (i.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry optTextMap=(Map.Entry)i.next();
        Map.Entry optAnswerMap=(Map.Entry)i2.next();
        RadioButton radioButton=new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setTag(optAnswerMap.getValue().toString());
        radioButton.setText(optTextMap.getValue().toString());
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }
}
```

and I have a forward button that checks which Radio Button is clicked;

```
           if (masterkey.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("CS")) {
               if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please select an option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               }
               int selectedID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
               RadioButton selectedRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedID);
               keyTag = selectedRadio.getTag().toString();
               backList.add(masterkey);
               masterkey = keyTag;
               createScreen(masterkey);
               break;
           }
```

My problems is the selected index, or the results of;

> radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()

does not get cleared even though I remove the views. So the `keyTag = selectedRadio.getTag().toString();` gives a nullPointerException.

Please let me know how to reset the selected index of a radiogroup.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
raduiGroup.clearCheck();
```

will clear the selection.